# Bootstrap 4: Update value of second bootstrap select on select of first bootstrap select

Tags: angular, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two select fields. I want to know how to update the value of the second select picker based on the selection of the first one.

so far here is what I ahve:
form html:

```
  <form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">


        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #cityName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.cityName">{{city.cityName}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #hotelName>
            <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.hotelName">{{hotel.hotelName}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" (click)="addReview(date, email.value, cityName.value , hotelName.value)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-element_btn"
            [disabled]="!validEmail">Book</button>
        </div>

    </form>
```

here is JSON file which holds city and hotel

```
  cities = [
        {
          'cityName': 'Berlin',
        },
        {
          'cityName': 'Oslo',

        }
      ];
      hotels = [
        {
          'cityName': 'oslo',
          'hotelName': 'Sheraton Hotel',

        },
        {
          'cityName': 'Berlin',
          'hotelName': 'grand hotel',

        }
      ];
```

Can someone help out on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qezkt4)

HTML:

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">
    <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #cityName (change)="changeSelect(cityName.value)" formControlName='city'>
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.cityName">{{city.cityName}}</option>

          </select>
    </div>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
        <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #hotelName formControlName='hotel'>
            <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.hotelName">{{hotel.hotelName}}</option>

          </select>
    </div>
</form>
```

TS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  angForm: FormGroup;
  cities = [
    {
      cityName: 'Berlin',
    },
    {
      cityName: 'oslo',

    }
  ];

  hotels: Array<any> = [
    {
      cityName: 'oslo',
      hotelName: 'Sheraton Hotel',

    },
    {
      cityName: 'Berlin',
      hotelName: 'grand hotel',

    }
  ];

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();

  }

  createForm() {
    this.angForm = this.fb.group({
      city: this.cities[0].cityName,
      hotel: this.hotels[0].hotelName

    })
  }

  changeSelect(event) {
    let ret = this.hotels.find(data => data.cityName.toString() === event.split(': ')[1].toString());
    this.angForm.get('hotel').setValue(ret.hotelName);
  }

}
```

Comment: Perfect solution , Thank you UnluckAj

Comment: UnclukyAj, I am using calendar in my form this one from https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/calendar.html#events  , may be u know how can I disable the past dates in this calendar?  if you know , I can add a thread nd accept your answer.

Comment: here is the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51223435/igx-calendar-ui-for-angular

Answer (score 1):

Please made the following changes that i made in your code
 HTML code

```
<form [formGroup]="angForm" class="form-element">
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_city">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #cityName (change)="changeFun(cityName.value)" formControlName='city'>
            <option selected *ngFor="let city of cities" [ngValue]="city.cityName">{{city.cityName}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group mb-3 form-element_hotel">
          <select class="custom-select" id="inputGroupSelect01" #hotelName formControlName='hotel'>
            <option selected *ngFor="let hotel of hotels" [ngValue]="hotel.hotelName">{{hotel.hotelName}}</option>

          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <button type="submit" (click)="addReview(date, email.value, cityName.value , hotelName.value)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block form-element_btn"
            [disabled]="!validEmail">Book</button>
        </div>

  </form>
```

Write below function in your .ts file

```
changeFun(value) {
  const temp = this.hotels.find(k => k.cityName === value);
  const current_hotel = temp.hotelName;
  setTimeout(() => {
              this.angForm.controls['hotel'].setValue(current_hotel);
            }, 0);
  }
```

You can use Reactiveforms for the same