# Disable single date in p-calendar

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4, primeng

I have a calender and I want to disiable a certain date eg 10/7/2018, I am using [p-calendar](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar)

Here is what I have done so far

```
<p-calendar formControlName="date" [inline]="true" [disabledDays]="[10]"  [minDate]="minimumDate" tabindex="0">
        <ng-template pTemplate="date" let-date>
            <span [ngStyle]="{backgroundColor: (date.day ==10) ? '#7cc67c' : 'inherit'}"   style="border-radius:50%">{{date.day}}</span>
        </ng-template>
    </p-calendar>
```

This does not work ,

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You're using `[disabledDays]`, where each value represents a day of the week, so any value > 6 is invalid. You want `disabledDates` instead, which should be an array of `Date` objects.

Comment: aah ur right thanks for help am just learning  bro, I will check it if it works I will aceept the answer if you put it  like before, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `[disabledDays]`, where each value represents a day of the week, so any value > 6 is invalid. You want `disabledDates` instead, which should be an array of `Date` objects.

There should be more info in the documentation that you linked to.

Comment: This works good if I want to disabled eg todays date. look here is what I have ``ngOnInit() {
    const today = new Date();
    const invalidDate = new Date();
    invalidDate.setDate(today.getDate() - 1);
    this.restictedBookingDates = [today, invalidDate];
  }``    what do I need to change in my function so that I can pass different dates eg [6,9,10, 10] ?

Comment: You'll need to set the date on your Date object. Have a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate